# Why do I *occasionally* throw a KeyError?

Tags: python

```
import random

tarot = { 1: "The Magician", 2: "The High Priestess", 3: "The Empress", 4:
"The Emperor", 5: "The Hierophant", 6: "The Lovers", 7: "The Chariot", 8:
"Strength", 9: "The Hermit", 10: "Wheel of Fortune", 11: "Justice", 12:
"The Hanged Man", 13: "Death", 14: "Temperance", 15: "The Devil", 16:
"The Tower", 17: "The Star", 18: "The Moon", 19: "The Sun", 20: "Judgement",
21: "The World", 22: "The Fool"}

spread = {}

past = 0

present = 0

future = 0

for i in range(0,2):
    past = random.randint(1,22)
    if past not in tarot.keys():
        past = random.randint(1,22)
    spread['past'] = tarot.pop(past)
    present = random.randint(1,22)
    if present not in tarot.keys():
        present = random.randint(1,22)
    spread['present'] = tarot.pop(present)
    future = random.randint(1,22)
    if future not in tarot.keys():
        future = random.randint(1,22)
    spread['future'] = tarot.pop(future)


for key, value in spread.items():
    print(f"Your {key} is the {value} card.")
```

This occasionally throws a KeyError, in cases when the int that is the key has already been popped from tarot. But I have checks to re-roll in those cases, do I not?

Answer (score 1):

Your program crashes when it happens to pick a used card twice in a row. You do check for that, but only once.

Change your card drawing like this:

```py
    future = random.randint(1,22)
    while future not in tarot.keys():    # while instead of if
        future = random.randint(1,22)
    spread['future'] = tarot.pop(future)
```

Comment: solved by using random.choice(list(tarot.keys))) and getting rid of all if not in